# Java Massive Multiplayer Game Server Scaleability

Tags: java, multithreading, tcp, concurrency, garbage-collection

I've created a massively multiplayer online game for Android called The Infinite Black:
https://market.android.com/details?id=theinfiniteblack.client

In my naivety, I was expecting moderate growth rate of about 1,000 players a month, and needing to manage ~20 live TCP/IP clients tops.

The game has had unexpectedly explosive growth with over 40,000 new users in a week, and is averaging ~300 live connections at once, and growing exponentially.

The server architecture consists of 2 threads per connection (blocking read/write), one ServerSocket thread to spawn off new clients, and one controller thread that polls each client for new actions, applies it to the game world, then flushes data back out when done.

The server is built in Java which I'm not very well versed in, particularly in a high-stress situation such as this. C# has really spoiled me when it comes to memory and thread management.

To get to the point.. I've just ordered two very powerful systems to run as dedicated game servers and want to maximize resource use. A lot of the information on Java resource configuration has proven to be misleading, incorrect, or out of date.

I currently use -Xss512k as my launch argument, and understand that this dictates stack size allotment for each thread, but I don't fully comprehend all that it may entail. What tools or methods are available to tell me if I'm overshooting the mark and can scale it down? What other command line arguments should I consider?

The new servers have 16gb of RAM and i7-2600K Sandy Bridge 3.4GHz processors: What options are available in configuration to take as much advantage of this as possible? My goal is 1,200 online clients at once per server (2,400 threads).

What kind of unexpected pitfalls and problems should I be concerned with?

I've read wildly conflicting stories on maximum thread counts: Will things fall apart if I'm trying to push 2,400 active threads?

Java doesn't seem like it was designed for this type of task. Should I consider migrating the server to another language?

I currently run the server in debug mode out of Eclipse while it's in development (ugh..)

This is my Eclipse .ini configuration:

--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M

-Xms256m

-Xmx1024m

Comment: Actually, Java was designed for this task. :-)

Comment: Yeah who'd ever thought of using Java for massive servers? ;) But the problem is sadly the whole solution - 2threads/user just doesn't scale properly, no language would help there.

Comment: http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html How to scale modern TCP servers to tens of thousands of TCP connections

Answer (score 8):

You haven't made it clear where your doubt comes from.

[Plurk Comet: Handling 100,000+ Concurrent Connections with Netty (2009)](http://www.jboss.org/netty/performance/20090607-asalihefendic.html)

In 1999 I deployed a Java web server which handled 40,000 yellow pages search queries per hour (the servers had 400 MHz CPUs) and in 2004 I development a Java application which handled 8000 concurrent connections per server (on a dual 1.2 GHz Sparc servers) There were six gateway servers and one main server to control them and centralise events.

Your profile is likely to be different, but I can say that Java was supporting high volume web servers before C# was released.

Personally I wouldn't have more than 10,000 concurrent connection per server, but this is just a rule of thumb which may no longer hold.  You can have 32,000 threads in a single JVM.  On Linux it doesn't go much beyond this. However I would have multiple gateway JVMs on a single server to minimise your full GC times (the best way to minimise full GC times is to discard less garbage, but this could require more effort)

> The new servers have 16gb of RAM and i7-2600K Sandy Bridge 3.4GHz processors: What options are available in configuration to take as much advantage of this as possible? My goal is 1,200 online clients at once per server (2,400 threads).

I can't imagine why this would be a problem.

> What kind of unexpected pitfalls and problems should I be concerned with?

Thinking you need to turn every possible command line parameter when it is likely you can take all of them away. If you have 4 gateway JVMs with 300 connection each, this can use all the memory and you won't even need to specify the -Xmx setting.

> Java doesn't seem like it was designed for this type of task. Should I consider migrating the server to another language?

You are better off asking yourself why you believe this.  You have a problem which should be simple to solve or a doubt which may or may not be unfounded.

> This is my Eclipse .ini configuration:

How you configure eclipse has no barring on how any program run from eclipse is set.

BufferedOutputStream is fine for most applications and is likely to be fine for up to 1000 connections in a JVM.  However Java 1.4 (2002) added NIO which is a more light weight for scaling your system to 10,000 connections and beyond.

BTW: The server I developed in 2003 was based on NIO dispatcher, but its pretty complicated unless you use a standard library like Netty.

Since then I have use a single thread per connection model for blocking NIO successfully. I believe this is simpler to manage than using a dispatcher and can have lower latency characteristics. I have a monitor thread which periodically checks connections are not blocking on writes and closes them if they are. I don't believe you need two threads per connection, but I don't believe it will make a difference in your situation because you won't have enough connections per server to matter.

As glowcoder suggests have you considered using UDP for less critical broadcast information?

Comment: Using a gateway or portal between external clients and internal systems is a common pattern used in a variety of distributed application whether its a web server or messaging based system in Java or any other language.  This allows you to scale the number of users relatively easily.

Comment: If you have a 16 GB system and you are distributing your work between about 4 JVMs you could run them with default settings and still use the whole server efficiently.  You may find you want to tweak something here and there, but generally speaking tuning parameters are over used IMHO.  On the other hand, unless you have put a lot of effort into making your application use memory in a scalable way in a single JVM you won't be able to use 16 GB of memory efficiently or anything like it.

Comment: The 64-bit JVM has full run of the memory, however as a game designer you will be concerned about latency esp worst case latency.  For a typical application the worst case latency for a Full GC is about one second per GB.  I am assuming a 16 second stop the world GC would be unacceptable to users.

Comment: If you put all your users into one JVM (which is bad idea for many reasons) and you have over 30,000 threads you will hit a wall.

Comment: Put another way, what is the maximum acceptable lag you can have? I am guessing between 0.5 and 4 seconds. That is likely to be the maximum size in GB for any single JVM in your system.

Comment: No problem. If you have one JVM, the simplest thing you do is to give it almost all the memory for its heap, say 12 GB and see how it performs. It sounds like scalability wasn't designed in from the start and Java won't fix that for you (I don't know of any language which will) You will see scalability issues but it should all still work or can be made to work without a re-write.

Comment: I would interested to know how .NET makes this problem any easier. ;)

Comment: Let me put it to you another way.  When Sun released Java in 1996, it had already released Solaris 2.5 (its 5th minor update of its 64-bit OS) Microsoft had just released its first 32-bit OS a year earlier and its flagship product, MS Office, was not 32-bit yet. .NET came 6 years later and wasn't 64-bit until about 4 years ago. Sun and Oracle have targeted larger, server systems for a lot longer (whereas MS has dominated the desktop market)

Comment: Your experience with productivity in C# doesn't surprise me. Visual Studio is an excellent commercial product. I don't really like Eclipse as you seem to need loads of ill fitting plugins to make it fully featured.  This is why I use IntelliJ which is another commercial product and much more productive IMHO.  It has a free version as well.

Comment: Rather than C# vs Java, I imagine we would agree on Eclipse vs Visual Studio. ;)

Comment: btw, why do you consider NIO hard? In a couple of thousands code one can write a decent server. Ensuring fair treatment of each session might be a bit tricky, though. Yet, a queue per client session + queue per sender thread is a straightforward and simple design (and can be totally lock free, except Selector.wakeup that's rarely needed)

Comment: NIO isn't hard but its not as simple as blocking IO. I recommend not making things more complicated than they need to be and if the simplest solution will do the job (and in many cases it will) I would suggest that is the approach to take.

Answer (score 4):

In Java, each thread will take the same amount of memory on the stack as any other thread. This means your main thread, let's say it has a reserved size of 32k (which I think is default) will be the same reserved size as your communication threads (which probably only need 1k, if you think about it!) This is why Java came up with nio - so you don't need a thread per connection.

Let's give the 1g of RAM example. With 32k per thread, assuming we have half our memory for stack and half for heap, we end up with 512 available for stack. This gives us room for 16,384 threads. This also means our thread scheduler has to juggle 16,384 threads. This greatly increases the chance that one of the threads will get starved. Now if one person gets starved, well sucks to be him; if `main` gets starved, sucks to be ... everyone!

With nio, you have... two threads. Main, and communication. (You could even do it without the communication thread, actually...). Now actually you probably have a bit more than that as you have a game loop and such. But still 10 threads is much easier to schedule properly than 16k threads!

Nio isn't necessarily intuitive to learn, but it's well worth it.

One thing I would consider if you're not going to use nio is to only have 1 thread per connection instead of two. You don't need a second one for writing: you can have a thread with a queue and have it do all the writing for all clients. That will at least double your throughput for the time being.

Comment: `flush()`ing a socket shouldn't block your Java code - rather it should it to a hardware layer for processing so it must be the buffered part that is blocking. If you're going to manually flush, consider not using a `BufferedOutputStream`. Depending on what you're sending across, I'd consider using `DataOutputStream` or `ObjcetOutputStream` accordingly.

Comment: As an indie game developer myself, I can tell you that switching to nio isn't as painful as it sounds. It will take a few days, but you'll be able to service as many clients on a server as it has the CPU and RAM to handle their game (as opposed to being limited by the thread communication). My estimates when I was looking at an mmo were at 1k with conventional sockets and 15k with nio. Buying 15 times less servers seems worth it to me!

Comment: Rather than doing NIO manually, you may want to take a look at Netty (www.jboss.org/netty). It should take care of a lot of plumbing for you.

That being said, Java should easily handle several thousand threads without issue if they aren't all sending at once so you may have a little cushion with these very new servers.

Comment: @AngerClown depends. Typically your clients have two threads going for communication: 1 TCP for important information, 1 for UDP for background information. If everything is condensed into one thread, chances are you have a constant stream of information

Comment: @glowcoder, can you explain why would you have 2 channels, you may need to synchronize 'em which sucks. If I am to opt for UDP just transfer the delta state (incl) background, the only difference between TCP/UDP would be favoring TCP of the providers. UDP can survive w/ NAK most of the time, greatly reducing the bandwidth and load.

Comment: @bestsss You still want player requests (like movement, actions, etc) to go through on TCP. Otherwise you'd have to implement your own SYN/ACK/NAK protocol, which is just silly.

Comment: @glowcoder, yeah about client requests, i meant mostly server->client, client->server should be significantly less loaded channel.

Comment: @bestsss there wouldn't be any client->server communication over UDP. The only thing the client needs to tell the server is its requests. So you have one UDP channel (broadcast gamestate delta), one TCP channel (to server is client requests, from server is periodic gamestate refresh to overcome UDP packet loss, and client request results).

Answer (score -3):

You must not think in load by nodes neither in amount of threads.
1)
If your games scale to millions users you need cluster of servers loadbalanced by a registry

2) Each node must be low latency meaning each incoming player messages and world update computation (1 tick) must be done  milli seconds. Very doable. No need to have monster configuration per node.

3) call this 30 times per seconds

=> you can have thousands simultaneous players on a single node and scale ten thousansd to millions with region segmentation thanks to a registry in front of your infrastructure that ensure players are connected to the best ping latency game server.

With this pattern loaded 10 000 simultaneous  player on realtime game per node  and +300 000 per node on turn based game.

Bottleneck is often IO. Use SSD for database storage.

Java is not a problem. 2400 thread is a problem. You can solve the problem with loop time spent and must consider under millisecond tick loop.

HTH

Nuggeta admin - [100% Free high load multiplayer java game server](http://nuggeta.com)